# Why isn´t it possible to change a reference object of an entity with JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a ticket object which should be edited. In my ticket object are attributes which reference to object(see below).

```
...
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "project_id", referencedColumnName="id")
private Project project;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "costCenter_id", referencedColumnName="id")
private CostCenter costCenter;
...
```

But when I try to update the entity I always get an error:

> Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction

```
@PutMapping("/tickets/{id}")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public Ticket updateTicket(@RequestBody Ticket ticket) throws Exception{
    Optional<Ticket> o = this.ticketRepo.findById(ticket.getId());
    o.ifPresent(element -> {
        if(ticket.getCostCenter() != null) {
            Optional<CostCenter> c = this.costCenterRepo.findById(ticket.getCostCenter().getId());
            c.ifPresent( costCenter -> {
                element.setCostCenter(costCenter);
            });
        }
        if(ticket.getProject() != null) {
            Optional<Project> p = this.projectRepo.findById(ticket.getProject().getId());
            p.ifPresent(project -> {
                element.setProject(project);
            });
        }
        this.ticketRepo.save(element);
    });
    return o.orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException(ticket.getId()));
}
```

PS: When I trigger the update without changes everything works fine.

Stacktrace: https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/2vm5

```
class AuditorAwareImpl implements AuditorAware<Long> {

    @Override
    public Optional<Long> getCurrentAuditor() {
        PersonRepository personRepo = ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean(PersonRepository.class);
        if(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null) {
            Person p = personRepo.findByUserPrincipalName(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName() + "@email.com");
            return Optional.of(p.getId());
        } else {
            Person p = personRepo.findByUserPrincipalName("SYSTEM");
            return Optional.of(p.getId());
        }
    }
}

@Component(value = "applicationContextProvider")
class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static class AplicationContextHolder {
        private static final InnerContextResource CONTEXT_PROV = new InnerContextResource();
    }

    private static final class InnerContextResource {

        private ApplicationContext context;

        private void setContext(ApplicationContext context) {
            this.context = context;
        }
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return AplicationContextHolder.CONTEXT_PROV.context;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ac) {
        AplicationContextHolder.CONTEXT_PROV.setContext(ac);
    }

}
```

```
@Data
@Getter
@Setter
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    protected Long id;

    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdAt;

    @CreatedBy
    private Long createdBy;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date updatedAt;

    @LastModifiedBy
    private Long updatedBy;

    @PrePersist
    protected void prePersist() {
        if (this.createdAt == null) createdAt = new Date();
        if (this.updatedAt == null) updatedAt = new Date();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    protected void preUpdate() {
        this.updatedAt = new Date();
    }

    @PreRemove
    protected void preRemove() {
        this.updatedAt = new Date();
    }

}
```

Comment: I think that you must use `CascadeType` for your relations

Comment: On the other hand, I suposse that this method it's only for test, you musn't send entities thought the controller.

Comment: Post the entire untrimmed stack trace.

Comment: i have uploaded the full stacktrace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a `StackOverflowError` which strongly suggest you've got some infinite recursion somewhere (or at least a very deep one):

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

The fact that `com.mycompany.test.config.AuditorAwareImpl.getCurrentAuditor` shows up repeatedly in your very long stack trace suggests that it is somehow involved in your infinite recursion and I'd wager that it comes from this class somehow triggering whatever triggered it in the first place possibly `org.springframework.data.auditing.AuditingHandler`. So check your `AuditorAwareImpl` code and/or the auditing configuration.

Comment: I checked that but I can´t find any error. I have added my AuditorAwareImpl and my BaseEntity where I use it.

Comment: @JuNe: I can't really tell without much more content, but it seems that something during the `findByUserPrincipalName` call triggers a flush/commit which in turn triggers the AuditorAwareImpl which calls `findByUserPrincipalName` which triggers the AuditorAwareImpl which calls `findByUserPrincipalName` ...